# Controlling size of forms

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I have an Access application, and I'd like some forms to be maximised when they are opened, and others to be medium-sized when they are opened.  However, if I try something like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()
  DoCmd.Maximize
End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()
  DoCmd.Restore
End Sub
```

it has the effect of maximizing or restoring every open window, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Is there any way around this?

I'm using Access 2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217132/controlling-size-of-forms-in-access#217137) is 100% right when saying that either all are maximised, or none. If you really want to manage this issue, you'll have to read a little bit [**here**](http://www.utteraccess.com/forums/printthread.php?Cat=&Board=84&main=642287&type=thread) (look at the code proposed and the way to call it), understand what is done, and eventually build your own solution depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Access is an MDI (Multiple Document Interface) application, and this is how they work: either all sub-windows are maximized, or none.

What you need to do, is find a way to discover the dimensions of the Access application window, and then programmatically set the form's .InsideWidth and .InsideHeight properties. The `Application` object has a `hwndAccessApp` that probably can be used with some Windows API call to find out its width and height.

#### addendum

Thanks to [Philippe Grondier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217132/controlling-size-of-forms-in-access#217772) for finding a relevant code sample, the general idea from the [code sample](https://www.utteraccess.com/forum/setting-form-height-width-t1439577.html) is:

- declare the following Win32 API elements:

  - `struct Rect` (`Type Rect…` in VBA)
  - `const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1` (for ShowWindow)
  - `GetParent` (given a hwnd, get its parent's hwnd)
  - `GetClientRect` (retrieve position and size from a hwnd)
  - `IsZoomed` (boolean; true if window is maximized)
  - `ShowWindow` (change the state of a window)
  - `MoveWindow` (to change the position and size of a window)
- if your form is maximized (`IsZoomed(frm.hWnd) = True`), then restore it (`ShowWindow frm.hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL`)
- get the MDI clients area from your form's hWnd (`GetClientRect GetParent(frm.hWnd, rect)`)
- use the rect data to change the position and size of your window (`MoveWindow frm.hWnd, 0, 0, rect.x2-rect.x1, rect.y2-rect.y1`)

(The above is basically the explanation of the code sample; I didn't copy-paste the code because I wasn't sure if the author allowed it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use MoveSize:

```
DoCmd.MoveSize 100,100
```

Further information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa141514(office.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options here: http://www.jamiessoftware.tk/articles/resolution.html

I used ADHResize in the past and it got the job done.