# Can you have your main screen on your database to be set to 'maximize' and then additional screens to be set as a 'pop up'?

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have recently made a database in Access which has one main screen ( well several but they all follow the same layout and format) and on the main screen there is buttons for example; add new employee.

Is there a way to set the 'main screen' so it is maximized all the time, and the additional screens for example 'add new employee' screens to be set as 'pop up' screens. When I say pop up I just mean not maximized, so the original form size.

If someone could help you will be an absolute life saver.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controlling size of forms in Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217132/controlling-size-of-forms-in-access)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the property Popup of your forms to Yes.