# Microsoft Access form opens minimised after its been changed

Tags: ms-access

Im having an intermittent problem where forms open in view mode but minimised, looking like a small inch-sized box with the 'X' close button visible.
It normally seems to happen when Ive made a change to the form or code in the forms module, but happens randomly when being used in view mode.
I can only get round it by either re-importing a backup of the form or making the form border sizeable, either way it's not too professional.

Any ideas how I can solve this one?

Answer (score 1):

Docmd.Restore seems to work on the form load event

Comment: I have used docmd.MoveSize on occasion when the form was just cranky.
  http://stackoverflow.com/a/217144/410959

Comment: what version of Access? I find that more hassle than it's worth sometimes